# Not able to apply aggregation to fetch results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to filter out documents in MongoDB. I am using lookup and match functions to filter out documents.
Below is my document where I want to filter out the object having nodeType as 'root' but it is not working. It is still including the object which is having nodeType as 'root'.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a427eefced0b045f0a6ee8"
  },
  "nodeType": "wave",
  "nodeAttributes": {
    "endDate": {
      "simpleValue": "2024-01-04"
    },
    "name": {
      "simpleValue": "wave1"
    },
    "countries": {
      "simpleValue": [
        {
          "name": "Brazil",
          "code": "BR",
          "applicableProjectCodes": [
            "D42",
            "D43",
            "D44"
          ],
          "_class": "com.myapp.port_mongo.entity.Country"
        },
        {
          "name": "Canada",
          "code": "CA",
          "applicableProjectCodes": [
            "D42",
            "D43"
          ],
          "_class": "com.myapp.port_mongo.entity.Country"
        }
      ]
    },
    "startDate": {
      "simpleValue": "2023-07-04"
    }
  },
  "_class": "com.myapp.port_mongo.entity.Node",
  "output": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "64a427eefced0b045f0a6eec"
      },
      "nodeType": "measure",
      "nodeAttributes": {
        "date": {
          "complexValue": {
            "$oid": "64a427eefced0b045f0a6eeb"
          }
        },
        "comment": {
          "complexValue": {
            "$oid": "64a427eefced0b045f0a6eea"
          }
        },
        "wave": {
          "complexValue": {
            "$oid": "64a427eefced0b045f0a6ee8"
          }
        }
      },
      "_class": "com.myapp.port_mongo.entity.Node"
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "64a427eefced0b045f0a6eef"
      },
      "nodeType": "root",
      "nodeAttributes": {
        "projectGroupCodes": {
          "simpleValue": [
            "D42",
            "D43",
            "D44"
          ]
        },
        "launch": {
          "complexValue": {
            "$oid": "64a427eefced0b045f0a6ee9"
          }
        },
        "section": {
          "simpleValue": [
            {
              "complexValue": {
                "$oid": "64a427eefced0b045f0a6eee"
              },
              "_class": "com.myapp.port_mongo.entity.Attribute"
            }
          ]
        },
        "projectGroupName": {
          "simpleValue": "DEV_TEST_2"
        },
        "wave": {
          "complexValue": {
            "$oid": "64a427eefced0b045f0a6ee8"
          }
        }
      },
      "_class": "com.myapp.port_mongo.entity.Node"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is my aggregate query.

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      nodeType: "wave",
      "nodeAttributes.name.simpleValue": "wave1",
      "nodeAttributes.countries.simpleValue.name":
        "Brazil",
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "node",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField:
        "nodeAttributes.wave.complexValue",
      as: "output",
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "output.nodeType": {
        $in: ["measure"],
      },
    },
  },
]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is your sample document the input doc from 1 collection or the result?   Is the `$lookup` on the same collection, i.e. a "self-JOIN"?   `nodeType` appears both in the top level of the doc (as a peer field to `_id`) and in the `output` array.   Can you simplify the input by eliminating all the `simplevalue` stuff and extra fields that are not part of your desired match?

Comment: It's not clear to me how many collections you're dealing with, but is this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/75A0Iun59PR) close to what you are looking for?